# Virtual machine hangs when trying to login after being idle for some time

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine

I'm using *Microsoft Virtual PC 2007* to run a Linux virtual machine, but after some time I can't login to it -- not from the instance on the localmachine or ssh in to the machine. Both give the same response.  The login process doesn't finish; the image shows where it stops:

[image]

This only happens when the vm has been running for some days, if I reboot it works fine again for some time before it locks up like this again.

Does anyone have an idea of why this is happening?

**Edit:** Here are the files.

`ls -l /var/pam.d/`:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1208 2011-01-20 09:17 common-account
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1260 2011-01-20 09:17 common-auth
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1509 2011-01-20 09:17 common-password
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1201 2011-01-20 09:17 common-session
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  182 2009-04-17 09:53 atd
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  384 2009-04-04 07:42 chfn
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  581 2009-04-04 07:42 chsh
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 3592 2009-04-04 07:42 login
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   92 2009-04-04 07:42 passwd
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2305 2009-04-04 07:42 su
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   69 2009-03-27 17:18 samba
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  520 2009-03-21 10:28 other
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  168 2009-02-20 18:24 ppp
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  119 2009-02-17 04:22 sudo
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1272 2009-01-28 21:58 sshd
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  289 2008-11-12 16:47 cron
```

`/etc/pam-.d/login`: (comments removed)

```
auth       optional   pam_faildelay.so  delay=3000000
auth       [success=ok ignore=ignore user_unknown=ignore default=die]  pam_securetty.so
auth       requisite  pam_nologin.so
session    required   pam_selinux.so close
session       required   pam_env.so readenv=1
session       required   pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale

@include common-auth

auth       optional   pam_group.so
session    required   pam_limits.so
session    optional   pam_lastlog.so
session    optional   pam_motd.so
session    optional   pam_mail.so standard

@include common-account
@include common-session
@include common-password

session required pam_selinux.so open
```

`/etc/pam.d/common-account`:

```
account[success=1 new_authtok_reqd=done default=ignore]pam_unix.so 
accountrequisitepam_deny.so
accountrequiredpam_permit.so
```

`/etc/pam.d/common-account`: common-auth

```
auth[success=1 default=ignore]pam_unix.so nullok_secure
authrequisitepam_deny.so
authrequiredpam_permit.so
authoptionalpam_smbpass.so migrate
```

`/etc/pam.d/common-auth session`: session

```
session[default=1]pam_permit.so
sessionrequisitepam_deny.so
sessionrequiredpam_permit.so
sessionrequiredpam_unix.so 
sessionoptionalpam_ck_connector.so nox11
```

`auth.log`:

(15:36 is problably when I tryed to ssh to the vm, and I got the fault and did a reboot.)

```
Jun 30 14:17:01 us CRON[1435]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jun 30 14:17:01 us CRON[1435]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jun 30 14:20:01 us CRON[1458]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jun 30 14:20:01 us CRON[1458]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul  4 15:36:35 us sshd[1945]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Jul  4 15:36:35 us sshd[1945]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Jul  4 15:36:37 us sshd[1945]: Received signal 15; terminating.
Jul  4 15:36:37 us sshd[2052]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Jul  4 15:36:37 us sshd[2052]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Jul  4 15:39:01 us CRON[2478]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul  4 15:39:01 us CRON[2478]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul  4 15:40:02 us CRON[2565]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul  4 15:40:08 us CRON[2565]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul  4 15:42:29 us login[2451]: pam_unix(login:session): session opened for user glennwiz by LOGIN(uid=0)
Jul  4 15:50:01 us CRON[2677]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul  4 15:50:02 us CRON[2677]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul  4 16:00:01 us CRON[2754]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul  4 16:00:01 us CRON[2756]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul  4 16:00:02 us CRON[2756]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul  4 16:00:02 us CRON[2754]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul  4 16:03:37 us sshd[2799]: Accepted password for glennwiz from 148.140.26.150 port 51330 ssh2
Jul  4 16:03:37 us sshd[2799]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user glennwiz by (uid=0)
```

Comment: We'll need more information to diagnose the problem. Log in over ssh (with e.g. PuTTY from Windows) and look at files in `/var/log` that get modified when you log in. Observe if the whole machine crashes or just the login attempt. What happens if you press `Ctrl+Alt+F2` while at that hung login prompt (nothing, or you go to a different console, and can you log in there)? Separately, to look for potential culprits: tell us the list of files in `/etc/pam.d/`.

Comment: i will monitor the changes in te log files the next time this happens, and i have added the pam.d files in an edit to the op, and when trying Ctrl+Alt+F2 it gived the same result it just hangs after password.

Comment: You mean you get a password prompt on the second console, and if you attempt to log in there it hangs too? Ok, so it's definitely a problem in a login method. That's what the `/etc/pam.d` stuff is about. Please post the contents of `/etc/pam.d/login`, `/etc/pam.d/common-account`, `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` and `/etc/pam.d/common-session`. Also, look under `/var/log` (especially `/var/log/auth.log`, perhaps in the `.0` file or `.1.gz` and so on) to see if there are logs from a time when you encountered the problem.

Comment: yes same issue in the second console to. updated with info with content in files.

Comment: I can't see anything unusual in your configuration. Hopefully someone will. If not, keep a root shell running on the machine, and when the problem reappears, use it to investigate (see what processes are running, what files they're accessing, that kind of things).

Comment: yeah i was thinking the same, so will monitor when it arises again.

Comment: What is the disk-setup for your VM? I saw similar behaviour on a physical machine that was under heavy IO disk load.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved a problem with a VirtualBox guest OS hanging every single time when the guest OS was idle for a few minutes: I disabled all power management functions (screen dimming, sleeping, hibernating) in the guest OS, and the problem vanished.   It seems this is a very frequent problem and probably is the flaky nature of power management inside a guest OS.